# Wicket: how to use the BodyTagAttributeModifier class?

Tags: wicket

i'm trying to dynamically add the class attribute to the body tag, and i came across this class. but i can't seem to understand how to use this class. i have something like this in my page class (or panel class, as i tried with that too):

```
add(new BodyTagAttributeModifier("class", "homepage", this));
```

this doesn't even compile, saying there's something wrong with the 2nd parameter. but i think String is automatically considered a Model in wicket, like the Label class. am i missing something here?

Comment: Strings aren't automatically models; I'd guess you were confused by the constructor syntax for Label.  Properly, it's  

`public Label(java.lang.String id, IModel model)`

but Wicket provides a convenience constructor  

`public Label(java.lang.String id, java.lang.String label)`

that just calls  

`Label(id, new Model(label))`

http://wicket.apache.org/docs/wicket-1.3.2/wicket/apidocs/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/Label.html#Label(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

What if you just add an wicket:id to the body attribute and use the AttributeAppender class? Or, if the body attribute already has an id, can't you just use this class?

http://wicket.sourceforge.net/apidocs/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html

Answer (score 1):

Some Wicket Components have this String-to-model-shortcut (like Label), but it's not a general feature. You have to convert your String into a Model manually:

```
add(new BodyTagAttributeModifier("class", Model.of("homepage"), this));
```