# Wicket - Add body tag attribute

Tags: wicket

I'm stuck -

I need to have a Wicket Panel be able to add a class attribute to the <body> tag of whatever page it's on.
Example usage:

Java:

```
add(new SpecialSidebarComponent("sidebar"));
```

Generated HTML:

```
<body class="sidebar">
   ...
   <div id="sidebar">My Wicket Panel</div>
   ...
</body>
```

I cannot add a wicket:id and make the body a Wicket component, because this makes it very difficult to add components to a page in the big page hierarchy I have, and it still also doesn't easily allow for a Panel to modify the body attribute.

I thought BodyTagAttributeModifier may be for this, but apparently it is for something else and cannot get it to function ( [Wicket: how to use the BodyTagAttributeModifier class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247820/wicket-how-to-use-the-bodytagattributemodifier-class) )

Any helpful ideas?

Update:

In looking at it, it appears the BodyTagAttributeModifier class is *only* for a Panel's parent tag, not the Page's <body> tag:

Example (Scala syntax):

```
class Home extends WebPage {
  add(new Sidebar("sidebar"))
}
class Sidebar(id: String) extends Panel(id) {
  add(new BodyTagAttributeModifier("class", true, new Model("layout-class"), getParent))
}
```

Template:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div wicket:id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendered:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="layout-class">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Very confusing name IMHO.   Doesn't solve the issue but at least makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think the Javascript option is the cleanest for this specific case.  However, your comment about `add(Component...)` being final leads me to believe that you might be interested in the `setTransparentResolver(true)` method.  Here's how it works...

BasePage.html

```
<body wicket:id="body">
    <div wicket:id="panel" />
</body>
```

BasePage.java

```
public class BasePage extends Page {

    public String bodyClass = "";

    public BasePage() {
       super();
       WebMarkupContainer bodyContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("body");
       bodyContainer.setTransparentResolver(true);
       bodyContainer.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("class", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "bodyClass")));
    }
}
```

MyPage.java (extends BasePage)

```
public class MyPage extends BasePage {

    public MyPage() {
        super();
        add(new SidebarPanel("panel"));
        super.bodyClass = "sidebar";
    }
}
```

Even though you are not adding the SidebarPanel directly to the bodyContainer in the BasePage, it will still work out because of `setTransparentResolver(true)`.

For your simple case, go with the Javascript.  For the general issue of feeling constrained by subclasses not being able to fit inside containers, be aware of transparent resolving.

Comment: Nice example, but I think the OP talks about having modifying the `Page`'s `<body>` from a `Panel` added in it, not a `Page` subclass.

Comment: Presuming every page extends `BasePage`, you can do `((BasePage) getPage()).bodyClass = ...`.  I've certainly done that a lot with custom methods on the base page.

Comment: Well, indeed, that's the way to go, as I also pointed out in my comments. I still fail to see what does `transparentResolver` and subclassing  contribute in this example, though.

Comment: Poster indicated that a `body` container makes it difficult to add components to the page - presumably because you'd have to prefix `bodyContainer.add(...)` to everything.  With a `transparentResolver`, you wouldn't need to do that.  Poster also indicated that he is using a `BasePage` type scenario.  I've done this a lot with a `Dialog` type component that has a wrapper container (a `Border`) but I don't want to have to add components to some container in a parent class.

Comment: Oh, great, now I see it, thanks for your comments :) +1, a transparent resolver is a good choice. Although in this case I would make a superclass of BasePage that would only hold the `<body>` tag and `<wicket:child>`.

Comment: It's rarely useful, but really cool when you can leverage it properly.  I loved it when creating dozens of complex dialogs with different components but the same frame.  The `FrameDialog` had a root container that was a transparent resolver and then `AddTextDialog extends FrameDialog` just added components like "normal".

Comment: Cool :-) Wicket is so, so powerful!

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't give the `<body>` tag a wicket:id (I'll assume you don't have a BasePage that every, or almost every, other page extends in which to abstract this), it'll be not possible to know at page render time (when that `<body>` tag is rendered) what class to append to it, it will be simply copied as is from your HTML to the output.

You could achieve the same via javascript, however. Make your `Panel` implement `IHeaderContributor` and use [`IHeaderResponse.renderOnDomReadyJavscript()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/IHeaderResponse.html#renderOnDomReadyJavascript%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public abstract class SpecialSidebarComponent(String id) extends Panel 
                 implements IHeaderContributor {
    .....
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response){
        String javascript = "document.body.setAttribute('class', 'sidebar');";
        response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript(javascript);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, hadn't considered the Javascript approach - looks interesting.
On the other point - I do have a base class, however with add(Component...) being final, it's a pain to add components from subclasses unless I create custom new methods like addComponent(...), etc.

Comment: If you've got a BasePage, why not use a wicket:id for the `<body`> tag and get it by means of `getPage().find()` (for instance) in the `Panel`'s `onBeforeRender` and add an `AttributeModifier` to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with BodyTagAttributeModifier, at least according to JavaDoc. The compilation problems in the linked article stem from the use of a non-existing Constructor...

in SpecialSidebarComponent you should be able to do this:

```
add(new BodyTagAttributeModifier("class", Model.of("sidebar"), this));
```

Can't try this right now because I'm not at my development computer...

Comment: Thanks mate - added info on what this class actually does, only applies to Panel's parent tag, not Page body